# Script that finds data in excel compares with xml and replace

Tags: excel, xml, typescript, powershell, replace

I have a table in excel like this:

```
name1 | value1
name2 | value2
name3 | value3
```

etc...

XML looks like this:

```
<items>
<name>name1</name>
<value>value1</value>
</items>
```

In most cases the value in xml is wrong e.g. "value75" under "name1" and I am trying to create a script that compares name and value with the one in excel and set correct value to XML file.
Any idea?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far, so we can help you with a specific problem. See [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I am really new with scripting and I am just thinking and looking for solutions, I would need an example of how to do it.